# Unable to show order : undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the problem of undefined method 'id' for nilLNilClass when I was trying to display the order.id in success.html.erb. Does anyone know how to assist me in this? Greatly appreciate all the help.

success.html.erb

```
Invoice Number: <%= @order.id %><br/>
Amount Paid: S$<%= @order.price_in_cents/100 %>
```

order_controller.rb

```
 def create
    @user = current_user
    @order = current_cart.build_order(order_params)
    @order.line_items = current_cart.line_items
    @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.amount = current_cart.total_price

  if @order.save

    if @order.purchase

       @order.line_items.each do |item| 
       @order_place = OrderPlace.new
       @order_place.place_id = item.place.id
       @order = current_order
       @order_place.order_id = item.order.id
       @order_place.save

    end
   Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil

    render :action => "success"

  else
    render :action => "failure"
  end
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

end

**Update

```
def current_order
  if session[:order_id]
      current_order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
end
end
```

Comment: Way to much going on in this controller action.... but first....what is  @order = current_order?

Comment: I have updated the current_order in the description. I wonder if I am doing it correctly

Comment: Ok, so we have a @order in the view that is essentially nil, so its not being set properly right? That line I enquired about is what is giving you problems, the code is ok but the logic is incorrect. Is that line meant to set the session[:order_id] variable?

Comment: Hi there, I realise that i face problems in executing the creation of a order instance correctly. However through this method, I am able to store the respective place id and order id to my order_place model that is used to retrieve the history of purchase

Comment: I have followed a railscast in establishing the paypal payment. However, I have difficulty finding where the order instance in actually created from the create method

Comment: The order is created on `if @order.save` ... I don't see where you're setting `session[:order_id]`

Comment: May I know how I should change it to make it right?

Comment: @order = current_cart.order, you don't need a current_order method since you can access the current_order tom the current_cart

Answer (score 0):

remove the current_order method
and remove the @order = current_order line.

I'd start there.